# Watch file using SASS without a command prompt window in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I want SASS to start at system startup and watch a file/directory the entire time. However, I don't want the command prompt window to appear. If I close the command prompt window, then SASS also stops watching the file.

How do I watch a file using SASS without having a command prompt window open?

Here's part of a .bat file ran at startup:

```
cd "C:\...\Server\"
sass --watch sass:www/css --style compressed
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your SASS batch file to read:

> **start** sass --watch sass:www/css --style compressed

This will spawn SASS as a new process, and it will be untied from the original command prompt window that started it.

Comment: But there will still be a command prompt window open. I don't want there to be a window open.